# How to install Get-ADTrust in Windows Server 2008R2?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

As far as I've read on the MS document that the `Get-ADTrust` applies to Windows 8.1, Windows PowerShell 4.0, Windows Server 2012 R2.

It makes me confused that it can be installed either in windows 8.1 or WP 4.0 or WS 2012 R2? At the moment, I try to run it on WS 2008 R2 and it gives me the error:

```
Get-ADTrust : The term 'Get-ADTrust' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADTrust
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-adtrust:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Are there any way to get in working WS 2008 R2?

Comment: On older Windows versions use [`netdom trust`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835085.aspx).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Tks, I thought that it can be done. But okay, this is another method to use. Good to know

Comment: Usually you can't install cmdlets from more recent Windows versions on older versions, b/c otherwise there wouldn't be enough incentive for people to buy new Windows licenses.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you'r right :D .. good to know this. So it means, if you plan to develop a tool written in Powershell for example which contains some modules in it. It would probably won't work if you execute it in other versions. It's kidda tampering, though

Comment: If you were to develop a module that is supposed to be run on a variety of Windows versions, you'd implement the approach that ensures the highest sensible level of backward compatibility. In this case for instance your module would probably wrap a function around a `netdom` call and parse the command output into custom objects. Or perhaps detect the operating system version and call `Get-ADTrust` if available, and `netdom` otherwise.